# which one is faster, fwrite to file or insert into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, fwrite

Currently, I'm inserting every single visitor's IP address into DB.

```
insert into visitor(IP) values($ipaddress)
```

If there are around 50 visitors at the same time, usage of CPU is getting high.
However, there is also another way to record visitor's IP by adding into some TXT file.

```
fwrite($file,$ip);
```

If fwrite to file performs better then inserting into DB, I will go for it.

Comment: Benchmark it...?

Comment: The main factor here is the structure of the data, whether write and read operations will be sequential or random. Appending to a file may even be faster in some situations than using a remote database server (assuming you have a fast file system), but that certainly will change the moment you try to insert a row inside the file content instead of appending it. Same for reading: if you always read the whole content, then a file might be faster if you have no parsing overhead, in all other situations a database will be the clear winner.

Comment: @arkascha the last time I tested, writing a small amount of data to a file is faster than establishing a connection to a MySQL database - even if it’s a local one. Never mind the actual write operation. Until you run into locking issues, then the file write gets slow.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Two things to remark to that: 1. that does not contradict what I said above: the issue with using plain files as data storage is not the actual opening, but the processing of the data. That can be trivial if it is sequential and no parser is required, but gets complex and time consuming of you have to parse, process, reassemble and write the whole file for each operation, obviously, then such solutions break down. And 2. a connection to a database server is opened _once_, it usually is persistent...

Comment: More details, please.  Is this via a Webserver?  Via PHP?  Via logging into MySQL directly?  Is the IP address available in a web log?  A TCP monitoring system?  Other?  Do you care about dups?  Do you want to count dups?  Etc, etc.  How many inserts/minute at peak times?  What will you do with the results -- will a sophisticated `SELECT` be handy?  Is it OK to have a 24-hour delay before the data can be read?  If not, some shorter delay?  My point is that there are different solutions for different situations.

Answer (score 4):

In low traffic conditions, `fwrite()` is much much faster, since it’s a simpler process.

In high traffic conditions, a properly setup database table will handle simultaneous writes more efficiently and provide better performance.

Depending on your server, you could have some failures with fwrite() under high load - be sure to look into how locking works and the various fopen() flags.

If you’re going with the database option, look into storage options and indexing and `insert ignore`. These will all significantly impact performance.